# JS: more efficient way to call an image

Tags: javascript, html, image, call

Hi I'm trying to output an image and my previous method is like this:

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/25ecg/2/

```
<select name="code" id="code" size="">
        <option value="">imgA</option>
        <option value="">imgB</option>
        <option value="">imgC</option>
        <option value="">imgD</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="showimg()" value="Display">
<img src="placeholder.png" id="placeholderImg" style="display: none;" />

function showimg() {
    var q = document.getElementById("code");
    var selected = q.options[q.selectedIndex].value;

    var src = "http://www.unc.edu/~matusiak/imgs/Under-Construction-1.gif";
    var img = document.getElementById("placeholderImg");
    img.src = src;
    img.style.display = "inline";
}
```

what it does is everytime the user change his/her option the image is also changed, works fine I guess, but currently I'm trying to do something like this,

Elaborate:

Input(label/textarea): ImageA.jpg
Button: Click me

Desired Output: Image pops out

Desired Process:

no more select options `<select name=""><opt...</select>`, when the button is click it will search from the "img2/" + selected + ".jpg"; which is locally

or if `<select name=""><opt...</select>` can't be removed, change  to something more of a variable because in the current setup it prompts an error in the console that's why I'm looking for a more efficient way

thnx all help is appreciated

***Update***

```
function addTheImage() 
{     var img = document.createElement('img');
     img.src = "http://....";   
  document.body.appendChild(img); 
}
```

Comment: What's the error on the console?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) @StefanoOrtisi

Comment: Well, that's because there is no placeholder.png on the fiddle...

Comment: I''ll edit it to show my current code

Comment: @spassvogel actually there is style="display: none;

Comment: What I'm trying to say is you get the 404 because the browser is trying to access 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/25ecg/2/show/placeholder.png' which does not exist.

Comment: is it what you're trying to do, Show image based on the dropdown selection? I can't see in your code except you're setting underconstruction image to `img` tag

Comment: @Салман no that was the idea behind the previous method, what I'm trying to do is just add an image that can be found in a local folder and delete it with the click of a button, I'm working on something, update it soon as my code is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function addimage() { 
      selected =  document.getElementById("country").value;
      var src = "img2/" + selected + ".jpg";
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = src; 
      container.appendChild(img);
      img.style.display = "inline";
    }

</script>

<body>
  <input class="buildaddress" id="country">
  <input type="button" onclick="addimage()" value="Display">
  <div id="container"></div>

</body>
```

Got my answer guys posting it for others, who mnight have the same problem, also asking for your opinions on how to limit it to one appendChild, cause its unlimited